# Modelling background image of a static camera to detect moving object

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am currently studying for a computer vision exam and would like to learn something.
The question is modelling a background of a static camera to detect moving objects like cars and pedestrians.

I first thought the best answer would be to use a frame difference technique but it has some deficiencies.What would be the best way to answer this question

Comment: there are two simple ways(that i know of) which can give better results than frame differencing. 1) calculate a moving average frame and then do absolute difference with the current frame. 2) mode finding. for every single pixel accumulate histogram of color values. your background model is the most frequently occuring value. and then you do frame differencing against this.

Answer (score 3):

The more sophisticated technique is background estimation and background subtraction. Check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/bgslibrary/) out. It tells you methods with original paper references.

'***Statistical methods using multiple gaussians***' is one of the most used ones.

Answer (score 0):

I used [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2%20BackgroundSubtractorMOG2) with success on a pedestrian counting application, with static background. What are the deficiencies you're complaining about with technique ? Do you have a couple of image examples ?